# altair: empty plot in facetted layout with grid lines

Tags: python, altair

I have a plot similar to this one with this toy data

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "sex": ["M", "F", "M", "F", "M"],
        "group": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
        "mark": ["pass", "pass", "fail", "pass", "fail"]
    }
)

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X("count(id)"),
    y=alt.Y("mark"),
    row=alt.Row("sex"),
    column=alt.Column("group")
)
```

[image]

The panel in the right top (F, group C) is empty and has no grid lines because the dataframe has no matching rows. How can I make sure that the grid lines also appear in this subplot?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in option for that, so you would have to add a matching row for that and another column that sets the opacity to zero for that quadrant only.

Comment: I see, thank you for letting me know. Difficult in my case, because this is inside a streamlit dashboard which receives new data on a daily basis, i.e. I do not know beforehand which (if any) panels will be empty.